# cblas.h on openSuse 13.1

Tags: lapack, opensuse, blas

I want to use blas and a lapack libraries on openSuse 13.1 I installed the blas-devel and lapack-devel packages and the staic versions as well. All would be good but the there were no header files installed. no blas.h or cblas.h and the same for lapack. Does anybody know how to get the header files installed?

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 0):

BLAS and LAPACK are Fortran libraries, you need C interfaces: lapacke-devel and cblas-devel. But as I remember, there is no cblas package in openSUSE 13.1, so you need to use [science project repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=science&package=cblas).